# Android - Accessing member's only websites from application

Tags: java, android, http, cookies

I'm trying to create an app for a certain website that has no mobile version to offer. The method I'm using is that I download the source code based on URL and read everything I want from it. Unfortunately, the website requires logging in to access the critical information.

When I download source code from the URL https://domain.com?user=user_name&pass=password, the site greets me by showing that user_name is logged in. But when I try to access member's only sites, for example, https://domain.com/members/page_1/, the source code shows me "Access error". So the problem is that the cookies don't stay alive.

Source code download function:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            Log.d(TAG, url);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just here to say

## ***NEVER PUT THE PASSWORD IN THE URL.***

It is a huge security concern.

---

In terms of the cookies staying alive part, you should be looking at the HTTP requests as they arrive to ensure that the actually do have the 'Set-Cookie' header on them. From the OP, it seems like the site is not actually issuing you any cookies.